# align one li below another li in a horizontal ul

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following layout:

[image: What I want]

What I've now is:

[image: What I've now]

How do I get `li.company` under the `li.name`?

I have tried to `float` the company li to the left and and making it the last li but that doesn't work keeps going to the same line. Any help will be appreciated.

**Here is my code:**

```css
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #4d4d4f;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
  width: 33vw;
}
.contact-widget-list,
.sender-info {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sender-info {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
}
.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
}
.sender-info li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.email-icon,
.calander-icon,
.dropdown-icon {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="flip">
  <ul class="sender-info">
    <li class="name">Name 123123</li>
    <li class="company">Company 123123</li>
    <li class="dropdown-icon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="calander-icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="email-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order of your `HTML` a bit. Place icons first in `HTML` and other items after it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="flip">
  <ul class="sender-info">

    <!-- Following icons should come first in HTML -->
    <li class="dropdown-icon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="calander-icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="email-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>

    <!-- Place following code after icons in HTML -->
    <li class="name">Name 123123</li>
    <li class="company">Company 123123</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And add following css:

```
.sender-info .name,
.sender-info .company {
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #4d4d4f;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
.contact-widget-list,
.sender-info {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sender-info {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
}
.sender-info li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.sender-info .name,
.sender-info .company {
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}
.email-icon,
.calander-icon,
.dropdown-icon {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="flip">
  <ul class="sender-info">
    <li class="dropdown-icon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="calander-icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="email-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="name">Name 123123</li>
    <li class="company">Company 123123</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```